# How can I make only the data table auto refresh after every 2 minutes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables-1.10

I am creating inbox mail at automatically refresh after 2 minutes, that  displays new mail display in the datatable. How can refresh my datatable?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a platform where we solve your homework. Please provide more details on your question, bits of code, any error stacks + your research so far so we can give you the best advice based on your findings so far!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you are using serverside processing. sth like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var table = $('#TableID').DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      //any other configuration options
      "ajax": "path/to/processor"
});
```

you can force it auto refresh making table's ajax param to reload every 120 second:

```
setInterval(function () {
      table.ajax.reload();
  }, 120000);
```

Comment: Note that for short timers (example: 0.5 second), this can leads to ask for a reload BEFORE the old one has finished. I would add some check around, like this: 
 let isReloading = false;
 
setInterval(
 function () {
  if (isReloading == true)
   return;
  isReloading = true;
  table.ajax.reload(
   function() {
    isReloading = false;
   }
  );
 },
 500
);

Comment: Using version 1.10, the call is `table.api().ajax.reload();`

Answer (score 3):

Considering you're using server-side processing for the Ajax-sourced datatable, all you need to do is redraw the table after every 2 minutes.

You can use Javascript's `setInterval()` function

```
var oTable = $("#mytable").DataTable({
                  'serverSide': 'true'
             });
```

After initialisation, use `setInterval()` to redraw the table with your desired time.

```
setInterval(function(){
    oTable.draw();
}, 120000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to call DataTable Object only ajax.reload() was not working for me

```
//Auto refresh Datatables on specified milliseconds
setInterval(function(){
    $('#workitemgrid').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    $('#exceptionqueuegrid').DataTable().ajax.reload();
}, 30000);
```